# ASIHTTPRequest Stalls

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to fetch data asynchronously. Initially everything works fine but after a random number of requests the requests stop loading. I've implemented all delegate methods and logged at each method and turns out that the request is being created but not being started i.e. the

```
- (void)requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

delegate method never gets fired. I tried to tackle it by adding a timeout timer. I initialized this timer when the request gets created and cancel it when it starts. The timer is working fine and retries to make requests but then the request never starts to load. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you assigned `request.delegate = self`?

Comment: Yes, and they get fired at first but after some requests they stop firing.